# Compose VectorImages for flavours

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose

I have a project created with jetpack compose UI, and as a vector image I'm using my own generated `ImageVector`s (Not drawable resources) objects like material icons has `Icons.Default.Close`, Now I have mine custom, like `MyIcons.Default.Close`.

Now the question is. How to setup these icons for another flavour's when it's need to show other icon for the same UI element (Icon).